# how do i select a row to compute matrix subtraction in c

Tags: c

I have matrix `A` of size 2x3 `{7 7 7,4 4 4}` and matrix `B` of size 2x3 `{4 4 4,1 1 1}` and an `array[c] = {5 5 2}`

I want the user to select a row to do the subtraction and if the row subtraction is bigger than the array it would ask the user to pick another row.

My problem is if I choose row 1 subtraction, `{7 7 7} - {4 4 4} = {3 3 3}`, the third value is bigger than `2`, it should break and ask user to pick another row, but my code didn't work that way.

```
while(count!=0){
  printf("enter row number");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  if(running[i]){
    exec=1;
    for(j=0;j<column;j++){
      if(A[i][j]-B[i][j]>array[j]){
        exec=0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(exec){
      printf("Row %d is executing\n",i+1);
      running[i]=0;
      count--;
      break;
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: it ouput "row 1 is executing"

Comment: explain r, running, count.. r should be no of columns

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the code below using do while loop,

Note: I'm statically initializing the arrays, if you want you can allocate dynamically using malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int rowNum,i,j;
   char execute = 'N' ;   // flag variable used to repeat the loop


   int A[2][3] = {7,7,7,4,4,4};       // Allocate the matrices dynamically if required
   int B[2][3] = {4,4,4,2,2,2} ;

   int c[3] = {5,5,2};

   do {
             execute = 'N';            
             printf("\nEnter row number to perform substraction:");
             scanf("%d",&rowNum);

             if(rowNum <= 2)   // checking whether entered row number is greater than 2

             {  
            for( i = rowNum-1, j =0 ; j <3 ; j++)
             {   
            if((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) > c[j] )
                {
                    execute = 'Y' ;
                    printf("Condition failed,Enter valid row number");
                    break ;
                    }


        }
    }
    else
    printf("Crossed max number of rows\n");
}

while(execute=='Y');


 return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: if i have 4 rows, row1 and row2 are eligible for subtraction. If row1 succeed, how to implement that it ask user to enter other row to perform subtraction

Comment: Add else block like else { execute = 'Y' ; continue ;} statements after if((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) > c[j] ) block.